# Why does not this example Vue.js 2 work?

Tags: vuejs2

https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/gfg30Lgv/ - here's the example that I want to use in my project. I've created files:
Tabs.vue:

```
Vue.component('query-browser-tab', {
    template: `
        <div id="queryBrowserTab">
            <h3>{{tab.name}}</h3>
        </div>`,
    data: function () {
        return {
            databaseOptions: [],
        };
    },
    props: ['tab'],
    methods: {}
});
```

Container.vue:

```
Vue.component('query-browser-container', {
    template: `
    <div id="queryBrowserContainer" style="margin-top: 50px;margin-left: 400px;">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" v-for="tab in tabs" :class="
{active:tab.isActive}">
            <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" @click.stop.prevent="setActive(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>

            </li>
            <li>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="openNewTab">New tab</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div v-for="tab in tabs" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" :class="{active:tab.isActive}">
        <query-browser-tab :tab="tab"></query-browser-tab>
    </div>
</div>
 <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
   </div>`,
   data: {
   tabs: [{
   name: "tab1",
   id : 0,
    isActive: true
}],
activeTab: {}
},
ready: function () {
this.setActive(this.tabs[0]);
},

methods: {
setActive: function (tab) {
var self = this;
tab.isActive = true;
this.activeTab = tab;
this.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
if (tab.id !== self.activeTab.id) { tab.isActive = false;}
});
},
openNewTab: function () {
newTab = {
name: "tab" + (this.tabs.length + 1),
id: this.tabs.length,
isActive: true
};
this.tabs.push(newTab);
this.setActive(newTab);
},

closeTab: function () {
    console.log("### CLOSE!");
}
}
});
```

Included files on a page. Then added tags

```
<query-browser-tab></query-browser-tab>
<query-browser-container></query-browser-container>
```

I do not use webpack in this project.\Console errors:
The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.

Error in render function: 
(found in )

Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

The previous components that I've made work fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance
> value in component definitions.

In your `query-browser-container` component you use `data: { ... }` and you must use the same data's code as `query-browser-tab` component :

```
data: function () {
  return {
    ...
  };
},
```

The doc is clear : [data must be a function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

Comment: I've made it a function and now there's an error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439768/why-is-object-not-defined