# Why is object not defined?

Tags: vuejs2

I want to try Vue.js 2 and started with a simple example. I've took this one from here https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/gfg30Lgv/ and created a simple project with it. After I divided this code into files the project doesn't work. So I've made a data property a function:

```
    data: function(){
        return {
            tabs: [{
                name: "tab1",
                id : 0,
                isActive: true
            }],
            activeTab: {}

        }    
    },
```

But there's an error in a console: Uncaught ReferenceError: newTab is not defined.

Project: https://github.com/rinatoptimus/vue-webpack-delete

File QueryBrowserContainer:

```
<template>
 <div id="queryBrowserContainer">
    <p>queryBrowserContainer text</p>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" v-for="tab in tabs" :class="{active:tab.isActive}">
            <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" @click.stop.prevent="setActive(tab)">{{ tab.name }}</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="openNewTab">New tab</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div v-for="tab in tabs" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" :class="{active:tab.isActive}">
            <app-querybrowsertab :tab="tab"></app-querybrowsertab>
        </div>
    </div>
    <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
</template>

 <script>
import QueryBrowserTab from './QueryBrowserTab.vue';
export default {
    data: function(){
        return {
            tabs: [{
                name: "tab1",
                id : 0,
                isActive: true
            }],
            activeTab: {}

        }    
    },


    ready: function () {
        this.setActive(this.tabs[0]);
    },

    methods: {
        setActive: function (tab) {
            var self = this;
            tab.isActive = true;
            this.activeTab = tab;
            /*this.activeTab.isActive = true;
            console.log("activeTab name=" + this.activeTab.name);*/
            this.tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
                if (tab.id !== self.activeTab.id) { tab.isActive = false;}
            });
        },
        openNewTab: function () {
            newTab = {
                name: "tab" + (this.tabs.length + 1),
                id: this.tabs.length,
                isActive: true
            };
            this.tabs.push(newTab);
            this.setActive(newTab);
            /*this.activeTab = newTab;
            console.log("### newtab name=" + newTab.name);*/

        },
        test: function() {
            alert('676767');
        },
        closeTab: function () {
            console.log("### CLOSE!");
        }
    }
}
```

File QueryBrowserTab:

```
<template>
 <div>
    <p>querybbbTab</p>
    <h3>{{tab.name}}</h3>
    <h3>{{tab.id}}</h3>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
    import QueryBrowserContainer from './QueryBrowserContainer.vue';
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                databaseOptions: [],
            };
        },
        props: ['tab'],

        methods: {},
       components: {
            'app-querybrowsercontainer': QueryBrowserContainer
        }
    }
</script>
```

File App:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <app-message></app-message>
    <app-querybrowsertab></app-querybrowsertab>
    <app-querybrowsercontainer></app-querybrowsercontainer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {}
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you add all relevant code in the question, dont see use of `newTab` here,

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: DO you see in console, which line is giving this error?

Comment: There's an error after page loads: http://joxi.ru/p279qR4Co8Mpzr and after click New tab button: http://joxi.ru/zANYRe6uByQO32

Comment: Some screenshots: http://joxi.ru/12MYae5uM1pGD2, http://joxi.ru/BA00k6GhJZGoLA

Answer (score 1):

It seems in file: **QueryBrowserTab**, you have not passed `tab` props, but you are using it, make sure you pass `tab` as props from whatever places you are using it.

As stated in the docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Props), you can pass props to a component like following:

```
<app-querybrowsertab :tab="tab"></app-querybrowsertab>
```

which you are already doing in **app-querybrowsercontainer**,but in file **App**, you are not passing the prop, which might be the source of error for you.

Comment: How to pass them? I've already tried to add props: ['tab'], in QueryBrowserContainer file.